# How to show merged config.xml?

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration

In magento all config.xml files from all modules are merged to a single file at the end.

Is it possible to show the content of that file for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I installed [n98-magerun](https://n98-magerun.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/installation.html)

Execute this command:

```
./n98-magerun.phar config:dump
```

Please prefer the above method, because it is the safest one. There is a risk that your frontend users can see your output if you are using other methods which are rendering the output in the frontend.

Alternative Method - if you like to only view specific config files e.g. `system.xml` (or of course config.xml):

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');            
echo Mage::getConfig()
->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')        
->getNode()
->asXML();            
exit;
```

Found [here](https://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration/).

> The **loadModulesConfiguration** method will look in each configured
>   module’s etc folder for a file with the passed in name (in this case,
>   system.xml). Magento has a number of other configuration files
>   (api.xml, wsdl.xml, wsdl2.xml, convert.xml, compilation.xml,
>   install.xml), and as a module developer you can leverage this
>   functionality to create your own.

Comment: Is there a similar function in M2 equivalent to this one to get webapi collection as xml? I see way to get di dependency dump but not webapi

Answer (score 3):

you can try to print the result of `Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->asXML()`